# I need to know what changes will help me to populate the property in Endeca Workbench Rule Manager Advance tab

Tags: endeca, endeca-workbench

I have create a new property in Endeca Developer Studio named pRandom. This field is AutoGen and data is mapped with a txt file which is generated by the third party vendor. I need this same property to appear in Endeca WorkBench --> Rule manager --> Any Rules --> Advance Tab

Comment: Which version of Endeca (Tools and Framework) are you using?

Comment: Look at chapter 3 in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35647_01/MerchandisingWorkbench.101/pdf/MerchandisingWorkbenchHelp.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Merchandising Workbench, then I do not believe that you can trigger a rule on a property. Dimensions must be used instead.

BTW, I do not see any advance tab in my Workbench installation.

Comment: sorry, i do not want to trigger a rule on the property, i want to add a property in Sortby dropdown under advance tab in Workbench under Rules setup.

Comment: I don't see any rules setup nor an advance tab in my workbench, we are using v 2.1.3.   As sorting of records based on a property is done in dev studio.